# ValidationEngine ajax call before validate extra Data Dynamic

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

Here is my Code

```
<input class="form-control validate[ajax[IsObjectNoExists,condRequired[Level_ID]]] text-box single-line" id="Object_No" name="Object_No" type="text" value="">
```

Custom Script (Works):

```
$.validationEngineLanguage.allRules["IsObjectNoBatchExists"] = {
      "url": "/DuplicateCheck/IsObjectNoBatchExists/",
      "extraDataDynamic": ['#Block_ID', '#Level_ID', '#Phase_ID', '#txtObjectNoFrom', '#txtObjectNoTo'],
      "alertTextOk": "* This Object No is available",
      "alertText": "* Some of Object No is NOT available within the Range",
      "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
};
```

Before calling the **ajax[IsObjectNoBatchExists]** i want to check this fields are not empty

```
"extraDataDynamic": ['#Block_ID', '#Level_ID', '#Phase_ID', '#txtObjectNoFrom', '#txtObjectNoTo']
```

Comment: Are #Block_ID, #Level_ID, etc are ids to your elements?

Comment: Yes, these are ids